Second Highest number in MAX function using DAX
I have a variable as below
VAR First_Higest_number = MAX( 'DF'[Number_Column] )
and I would like to find the Second_Higest_numberin DAX. How to get around with this ? many thanks in advance.

You might use the search first, as it seems to be a duplication
VAR Second_Higest_number  = MINX ( TOPN ( 2, 'DF', 'DF'[Number_Column] ), 'DF'[Number_Column] )

Another option:
var Second_Higest_number =
  CALCULATE(
    MAX('DF'[Number_Column]),
    'DF'[Number_Column] < First_Higest_number
  )

Or:
var Second_Higest_number =
  CALCULATE(
    MAX('DF'[Number_Column]),
    FILTER( 'DF', 'DF'[Number_Column] < MAX(First_Higest_number) )
  )


Note: This method appears faster and less computationally intensive than using INDEX or TOPN or whatever. With just a simple table with numbers from 1 - 25.000.000, using INDEX doesn't even work (resource issue) but these measures return values in ~100 ms or less. Drawback vs. INDEX is that you can't pick Nth value easily, but for second largest this is very efficient.
